# reasons that brought to PEP 263

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x, python-2.3

I was reading the [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) and I got stuck on this paragraph:

> In Python 2.1, Unicode literals can only be written using the
>       Latin-1 based encoding "unicode-escape". This makes the
>       programming environment rather unfriendly to Python users who live
>       and work in non-Latin-1 locales such as many of the Asian 
>       countries. Programmers can write their 8-bit strings using the
>       favorite encoding, but are bound to the "unicode-escape" encoding
>       for Unicode literals.

What does "unicode-escape" mean? How did people from asia wrote python files? Can someone show me how they wrote python source code before python 2.3? I just can't get why PEP 263 was introduced: i installed on my machine python 2.1.3 and I launched `python cod.py` where `cod.py` is a file encoded in utf-8 and all just worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Unicode-escape is a character in the form `'\xab'`, the `\x` means to take the next two characters and interpret them as a hex code to produce a single character.

Characters in Asian languages often take more than a single byte, so for example the character `草` might be `'\xe8\x8d\x89'`.

You could not use these characters in source code, except as part of a string literal (or perhaps a comment).

Comment: I don't understand, in python 2.1 couldn't I write `x = u'草'` ? Did I have to write `x = u'\xe8\x8d\x89'`?

Comment: @antox that's correct, because `草` doesn't exist in the Latin-1 character set. At least that's what I gather from the piece you quoted, I don't have any direct experience.